# Django JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, python, json, django, autocomplete

I am trying to add an autocomplete field to my form. But I can't get t to work. I have tried almost every tutorial.
The request is sent out fine,I'm gettin a 200 response. In the developer tools pane when I click the request ,on the Response tab I see the whole HTML file. Shouldn't there be a json formated something..?? 
Here's the code:

models.py

```
class Signers(models.Model):
    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py

```
def get_signers(request):
  if request.is_ajax():
    q = request.GET.get('term', '')
    signers = Signers.objects.filter(uid__icontains=q)[:20]
    results = []
    for s in signers:
      signer_json = {}
      signer_json['id'] = s.uid
      signer_json['label'] = s.uid
      signer_json['value'] = s.uid
      results.append(signer_json)
    data = json.dumps(results)
    print data
  else:
    data = 'fail'
  mimetype = 'application/json'
  return HttpResponse(data,mimetype)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^get_signers/', views.get_signers, name='get_signers'),
```

praxis.html (my template)

```
<script>

  $(function() {
    $("#id_signerIds").autocomplete({
      source: "get_signers/",
      minLength: 2,
    });
  });

</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

              $('#id_submissionTimestamp').hide();
              $('#id_issueDate').hide();
});
</script>

{% endblock page_head %}


{% block content %}

<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}

<!--some other fields here... -->

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="id_signerIds">Signers: </label>
  <input id="id_signerIds">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>

 </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: _"But I can't get t to work"_ What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @PacoH. when i type some number , no results are displayed below the input field like it was supposed to

Comment: I see. Try [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). If it doesn't work please include the response from the request to `get_signers/`

Comment: You have multiple problems, I think you want to make an ajax call but you initialize it nowhere. I would suggest to change "get_singers" in `source: "get_signers/",` to a variable and pass it like so  `source: "{{get_singers}}"`.
If you really want to make an ajax call(better solution but harder) you would have to trigger when the user hits a key send the typed keys to your view and send back some data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all as you are using Django i suggest you type the urls by name, like this if you change an url of a view you will not need to change it everywhere in the comments so instead of `source: "get_signers/",` you can do `source: "{% url 'get_signers' %}",`.

Now returning to the question i suggest you change the code to:

```
signers = Signers.objects.filter(uid__icontains=q)[:20]
results = []
for signer in signers:
    signer_json = signer.name
    results.append(signer_json)
```

To provide my working case i will give you my code:

**views.py**

```
def company_autocomplete(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        query = request.GET.get("term", "")
        companies = Company.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        results = []
        for company in companies:
            place_json = company.name
            results.append(place_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    mimetype = "application/json"
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^api/company-autocomplete/', company_autocomplete, name='company-autocomplete'),
```

**add_company.html**

```
...
<div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
  <label class="bmd-label-static" 
         for="company_autocomplete_input">Cerca azienda</label>
  <input id="company_autocomplete_input" class="form-control"
         placeholder="Nome azienda" style="width:500px">
</div>
... 
<button class="btn btn-raised btn-primary" type="submit"
        style="background-color:#1A88B9;">Aggiungi</button>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#company_autocomplete_input").autocomplete({
      source: "{% url 'company-autocomplete' %}",
      minLength: 1,
    });
  });
</script>
...
```

And the most important thing:
be sure to add jQuery before of your autocomplete input

```
<!-- jQuery !-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<!-- jQuery UI !-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can used name URL as source for jquery. Becuase that's in JQ, not int he template, and jquery doesn't know what {% url ....%} means. So it will do:

/currenturl/{% url .... %}?term=....

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions yes because Django will convert them into the string before.

Comment: You didn't actually test this, no?. I just did - and seems it will not. "source" is defined in JAVASCRIPT. The named url notation you're using is used by django TEMPLATE engine. This part of the code is NOT rendered by the renderer. Therefore what you're trying to call there is just <current root url>/{% url ... %}. You need to specify a URL string, or as the doc in datatables explain source as a function.

Comment: I guess I'm using an enternal file as opposed to scrip tag... maybe that behaves differently? But I still don't see a reason why the named url you provided would be parsed as an actual url.

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions The script is part of the diango template, so Django will translate it in the actual url; in the project I was working on it worked, maybe you are doing something different? Maybe I can help you solving your issue if you show me :)
EDIT: yes, if you are using it in an external file it will definitely not work, as you can see from what I provided the tag script is inside the html file

Comment: Makes sense. Imo, this is a problem. At some size, a proper management of js codes will be needed (e.g. import from files living in some dedicated js directory). It might even be fairly annoying, e.g. you have some prototype that works, then when you refactor the code & move the js code to files then the autocomplete stops working. But it doesn't throw an error. So you wouldn't know until you check the console network calls or logs I guess... or someone notices.

Comment: Why don’t you pass the variable you need to the script? I don’t know how are you doing this but if you are including some script like <script src=“” /> maybe you can pass the variables to the script as parameters

Comment: Or you can create a javascript class in which the constructor will need the parameters you need and in the html file you do something like: var var_name = new Class_Name(param1, ...)

Comment: Yes that would work. This does feel a bit hacky though - I guess for my part, I'd rather just hardcode the url in the source. Or, if I'm going to be doing that sort of things a lot, import it from some config/envars. At any rate it is a gotcha worthiwhile to be aware of, for the reason I outlined above.

Comment: The reason for using {% url ecc %} is that if you want to change it for any reason you only need to do it in Django itself and forget about all the other instances where you used it :)