# How do I add a search TextField in Django?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, search, autocomplete, textfield

I am using Django as my WebFramework.
I have a Database that we want to search through.

To enable a search with auto-completion we use ElasticSearch as library.
There we have a method that takes a string as input and returns a list of relevant similar strings.

Now we want to add a TextField on our website that displays these suggestions.
As soon as the user enters a character into the textfield the function mentioned above should be called and the strings that come as return parameter should be displayed.
The input should be updated after each additional character entered.
In the following I have a small graphic to better illustrate my desired behavior.

Is there a nice way to implement such a thing in django?

If it doesn't work with django I would be happy if you steer me in the right direction which tools etc. I have to use.

[image: Autocomplete]

Answer (score 1):

Create a view that receives a string variable, parses the database and returns a Jsonresponse.

Use jquery and Ajax to detect when the text field has an input change, make the Ajax request, return list of values and display in drop-down on text field.

[Here is a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47632896)